# How to pass paramters from Activity A, to the tabs of a TabHost(B activity)?

Tags: android, parameter-passing, bundle, tabwidget

i'm trying to pass a parameter from a activity Main, to the tabs of a MyTabWidget activity.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add data to the intent you are starting `MyTabWidget` activity and in `onCreate()` get the data.

Put example

`myIntent.putInt("MyInt", 2);`

Get example in onCreateMethod()

`getParent().getIntent().getExtra().getInt("MyInt");`

Answer (score -1):

One way is to send a broadcast from the main activity and to register a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `TabActivity`. I don't think it is the best solution, but I couldn't find anything else that worked.